# Is there a pattern or a method in C# to check if an (int 1,2,4,8,...) option is true or false

Tags: c#, enums, boolean-operations, bitflags

I like to write enum or integer to pass option to my methods. Is there a pattern or a method in C# to check if an (int 1,2,4,8,...) option is true or false. I think it should easily be possible via binary functions.

```
class Program
{
    public enum Option
    {
        Option_A = 1,
        Option_B = 2,
        Option_C = 4,
        Option_D = 8,
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int activeOption = 5; // Means I activeted the Option_A and Option_C
        if (IsOption(activeOption, Option.Option_A)) { /*do work*/ }
        if (IsOption(activeOption, Option.Option_B)) { /*do work*/ }
        if (IsOption(activeOption, Option.Option_C)) { /*do work*/ }
        if (IsOption(activeOption, Option.Option_D)) { /*do work*/ }
    }

    private static bool IsOption(int activeOption, Option option)
    {
        /*Evaluate if IsOption is true or false*/
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Am I limited the number of options that I can create like this?

Comment: Why are you using an int instead of an Option?

Comment: @Martinho if you look at the code sample, it is required that multiple options be selectable. An int is more space-efficient than a collection of Options.

Comment: @Robin: An Option enum is as space-efficient as an int. Guess why: it's actually an int.

Comment: @Dan you misspelled Martinho's name, so he might not see your question. The Option enum is the thing in *your code* called Option!

Comment: Am I limited the number of options that I can create like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your enum contains flags (or if you prefer, is a bitfield), you should add a [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) to it:

```
[Flags]
public enum Option
{
    Option_A = 1,
    Option_B = 2,
    Option_C = 4,
    Option_D = 8,
}
```

And then, checking is typically done with the bitwise and operator. A cast will also be needed, because you are using an `int` variable.

```
if(((Option)activeOption & Option.Option_A) != Option.Option_A) //...
```

If you want to encapsulate this nastiness away, check out the article linked in [Smudge202's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069869/is-there-a-pattern-or-a-method-in-c-to-check-if-an-int-1-2-4-8-option-is-t/6069942#6069942). If you are running .NET 4, you don't even need to do that: check [sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069869/is-there-a-pattern-or-a-method-in-c-to-check-if-an-int-1-2-4-8-option-is-t/6070172#6070172).

But you should really try using a variable of type `Option` directly, and combine the options with the bitwise or operator:

```
Option activeOption = Option.Option_A | Option.Option_C;
```

Of course using this scheme limits the number of options you can create. If you leave it as is, you can only create 32 different options, because an `int` (the default underlying type of an enum) has only 32-bits. If you use a `long` you can have 64 different options:

```
[Flags]
public enum Option : long
{
    Option_A = 1,
    Option_B = 2,
    Option_C = 4,
    Option_D = 8,
    // blah blah
}
```

However, if you need an arbitrary number of options, it's probably time to change strategies. You could make a custom type that behaves like an enum, but you'll probably be better off with just a regular, non-flags enum, and a [`HashSet<Option>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

```
public enum Option
{
    Option_A = 1, // notice the sequential values now
    Option_B = 2,
    Option_C = 3,
    Option_D = 4,
}

HashSet<Option> options = new HashSet<Option> { Option.Option_A, Option.Option_C };
if(options.Contains(Option.Option_A)) // ...
```

Comment: +1 for flags attribute.  The [link I posted](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37921/Enums-Flags-and-Csharp-Oh-my-bad-pun.aspx) as an answer shows an extension method you can use to simplify the code writing when testing for enum members which hopefully compliments your answer.

Comment: It will complement the answer. Also, [C# 4.0 will complement it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069869/is-there-a-pattern-or-a-method-in-c-to-check-if-an-int-1-2-4-8-option-is-t/6070172#6070172)

Comment: @Martinho Am I limited the number of options that I can create like this?

Comment: @Dran: see my edit. Also thanks @Smudge and @sehe. I mentioned your answers in mine.

Comment: @Martinho Thank you very much for this well documented answer

Comment: @Dran: glad to be of help. Also note my last edit. There was a corner case that I forget in there, and my check could fail (I'll leave out the how and why as an exercise for the reader).

Answer (score 3):

Use bitwise AND to check if the bits in `option` are set in `activeOption`. You also need to make both parameters the same type so the operator will work (you *are* checking the bits in an `Option` bitmask anyway):

```
private static bool IsOption(Option activeOption, Option option)
{
    return (activeOption & option) == option;
}
```

Comment: I get an error --> Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int'

Comment: @Dran Dane: You need to change your method sig so both parameters are of the same type.

Comment: Am I limited the number of options that I can create like this?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to FlagsAttribute mentioned, in C# there is the [Enum.HasFlag Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)

```
using System;

[Flags] public enum DinnerItems {
   None = 0,
   Entree = 1,
   Appetizer = 2,
   Side = 4,
   Dessert = 8,
   Beverage = 16, 
   BarBeverage = 32
}

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DinnerItems myOrder = DinnerItems.Appetizer | DinnerItems.Entree |
                            DinnerItems.Beverage | DinnerItems.Dessert;
      DinnerItems flagValue = DinnerItems.Entree | DinnerItems.Beverage;
      Console.WriteLine("{0} includes {1}: {2}", 
                        myOrder, flagValue, myOrder.HasFlag(flagValue));
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    Entree, Appetizer, Dessert, Beverage includes Entree, Beverage: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Enumerations that use Flag Attributes.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37921/Enums-Flags-and-Csharp-Oh-my-bad-pun.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can use `HasFlag`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Option activeOption = (Option)5; // Means I activeted the Option_A and Option_C
    if (activeOption.HasFlag(Option.Option_A)) { /*do work*/ }
    if (activeOption.HasFlag(Option.Option_B)) { /*do work*/ }
    if (activeOption.HasFlag(Option.Option_C)) { /*do work*/ }
    if (activeOption.HasFlag(Option.Option_D)) { /*do work*/ }
}
```